# Let $F=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ Prove: $F$ is Lipschitz $\iff \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $f$ be integrable on $[0,1]$ and let $F=\int_0^xf(t)dt$
>
> 1. Prove: $F$ is Lipschitz $\iff f\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$
> 2. Give and example for absolute continuous function which is not Lipschitz

$\Rightarrow:$ Let assume $F$ is Lipschitz therefore it is absolute continuous therefore $F'=f$ almost everywhere.

$F$ is Lipschitz therefore there is $M>0$ such that for all $x,y\in[0,1]$

$$\frac{|F(x)-F(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq M\iff |F'(x)\leq M \iff |f(x)|\leq M$$

(almost everywhere)

Can I finish here?

$\Leftarrow:$
$f\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ therefore almost everywhere $|f|\leq\|f\|_{\infty}=M$

WLOG $x<y$ then
$$|F(x)-F(y)|=|\int_x^yf|\leq \int_x^y|f|\leq \int_x^y M =(x-y)M\Rightarrow \frac{|F(x)-F(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq M$$

Is this valid?

2. we can take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 1):

For any integrable function $f$ the function $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $F'=f$ almost everywhere. This theorem is required to show that $f \in L^{\infty}$ whenever $F$ is Lipschitz. For other parts your answer is correct.